# How can I send an email as a laravel parameter in a function with angular?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am making a section where you can delete your account only if the input field matches your email. But it get a **Error: $parse:lexerr Lexer Error** when I try this.

**My html:**

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    value="" 
    ng-model="query"
    ng-model-options='{ debounce: 500 }' 
    ng-change="checkAccountEmail(query,{{ Auth::user()->email }})"
    ng-placeholder="Enter your email here">

<a ng-disabled="!enableDelete" href="/delete/account/{{ Auth::user()->id }}">Delete</a>
```

**My controller:**

```
gloopsApp.controller('DeleteAccountController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.enableDelete = false;

    $scope.checkAccountEmail = function(input,name) {

        if (input == name) {
            $scope.enableDelete = true;
        }
        else {
            $scope.enableDelete = false;
        } 
    };
}]);
```

**Error:**

> Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 38-38 [@] in
>   expression [checkAccountEmail(query,test@gmail.com].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are outputting directly the email and not quoting it. So the result will be something like this:

`checkAccountEmail(query, email@test.com)`

When you clearly want this:

`checkAccountEmail(query, 'email@test.com')`

To do that, just change this:

`ng-change="checkAccountEmail(query,{{ Auth::user()->email }})"`

To this:

`ng-change="checkAccountEmail(query,'{{ Auth::user()->email }}')"`